# Comments deleted on a closed question

Tags: support, closed-questions, comments

I noticed that some of my comments on a [question of mine](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/88305/13174) were deleted.

These comments were answering (now also deleted) comments by someone who asked me about why I thought that the question is on-topic.

Is there a good reason why my comments were deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry. I deleted the comments before the question was closed. I thought you convinced jsotola that the question is on topic and I didn't expect other members would think the question is off topic.

It is normal to delete obsolete [comments](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), because purpose of comments on SE posts is to clarify things and then the comments should be removed.

The question is on topic of course. Fritzing is a tool used in Arduino world.

To answer the question, I asked one more clarification in a comment 2 days ago, but you were distracted by the off topic discussion.

Comment: Hm, after my question was re-opened ~ 2 weeks ago, it was closed again today (with reason: 'off-topic'). I remember that you left a comment there some time ago telling close-voters to consider the question as on-topic. But this comment was removed, in the meantime. Perhaps you are somebody else considered that comment as obsolete. But given the fact that the question was closed again, perhaps it wasn't obsolete after all.

Comment: @maxschlepzig, I can't write an answer on Arduino SE about bug in a Fritzing component. We found the problem and it is not an Arduino based problem.

Comment: Well, usually the question itself determines whether it's on-topic or not. Not its possible answer. Answering it with: no, it's not a feature/misuse of fritzing but a bug in the component would be a valid answer btw. Funny how my question was first closed than re-opened and now closed again while it didn't change. Perhaps  the [Feel free to ask about anything related to Arduino.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) sentence doesn't really reflect reality.

Comment: @maxschlepzig, Using Fritzing is on topic. Fixing Fritzing is not. Even fixing some Arduino IDE bug is not on topic.

Comment: Couldn't disagree more. Imagine a stackoverflow question inquiring about some GCC behavior. Someone knows that the behavior is due to a GCC bug - and instead of just answering along the lines of 'the behavior you observe is caused by this bug, cf. link/bug number/etc.' that someone votes to close that question. Because it's a bug, you see. Since stackoverflow isn't about fixing bugs etc. This would be quite out of space.